# System Sounds Not Playing on iPhone 6s, iOS 9.0.1

Tags: ios, iphone

For whatever reason my new iPhone 6s doesn't always play system sounds, such as  the Siri chime (there's also no Taptic feedback), the "magnetic click" when I lock my iPhone (which sometimes does work), and others. Even though some other sounds do play, such as the charging chime.

When I had my iPhone 5s running iOS 9, though the Siri sound didn't play, I got vibration feedback when I summoned Siri. My iPad Air (also running iOS 9) **does** play all of the sounds.

So is this an iPhone 6s specific thing, where Apple's trying to limit sounds to make a more Apple Watch-like experience, a software bug, a Setting that I missed, or something else entirely?

Comment: This may be a bug and we'll just need to wait for 9.0.1+. I have the opposite of this problem. Sometimes I get sounds while all my sounds are disabled.

Comment: @y3sh That's kind of what I'm thinking. Do you have an iPhone 6S?

Comment: Added note: I have found several other bugs that I solved with toggling settings off/on and restarting the phone.

Comment: Yes I have a 6S

Comment: The other settings-toggle bugs include: message character counts appearing, predictive text on, transparency off, high contrast off, and motion off. Yep, it's still early for a stable release