# Make Siri Ding Again on Pressing Home Button

Tags: ios, siri, iphone

So according to [this Apple support article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204389), Siri doesn't make that bell sound after holding the Home button to launch it *on iPhones with iOS 9 or later*. Instead, it vibrates.

> On your iPad or iPod touch, Siri will chime when it's time to ask a question. If you have an iPhone with iOS 9 or later, Siri will vibrate instead. You'll only hear the chime on your iPhone with iOS 9 or later when you're using headphones.
>   Siri will also chime when you use "Hey Siri" on a device with iOS 9.

That's really unfortunate because I really liked that ding.

Does anyone know if there's a way to make Siri play the "ding" sound again without headphones or Hey Siri? (Aside from jailbreaking)

Comment: I'm very interested to see if anyone has a way to accomplish this, but I'm pretty sure that it's not currently possible. I also asked a question relating to this back in September when I first got my iPhone 6s: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/207792/138476 (it's not a duplicate, as mine didn't get any answers, just comments). We can always file complaints to Apple and hope that we get this option in later releases of iOS.

Comment: @RedEagle2000 My 6S makes the keyboard clicks and the lock sound. Did you get the yours to work yet? Was it just iOS update?

Comment: I never really had a problem with keyboard lock sounds (I used to use Swype then anyway), but I have noticed that the lock click plays more consistently, probably around 90% of the time, I don't know what update helped, but I'm using iOS 9.2 now. However, Siri still won't even make my iPhone vibrate, let alone make the old Siri chime.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I have found with ios 9 is to go to **Settings** > **Accessibility**, and turn Vibration *off*. Extra caveats can be found in the source link. 
Source: [apple.com discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7218417?start=0&tstart=0)

Comment: Good find, but I just tried it and it only turns the beep back on for _after_ you speak your command. Starting Siri is still silent; this setting makes it beep after you talk instead of vibrating. Thanks though :)

Comment: @Arc676 Hmm, you've got me there. I can say that it works for me, even when I've flipped the mute switch to the now-even-more-silent mode. Perhaps restarting your phone will help?

Comment: Could you provide some information about your device? I'm using an iPhone 6S, iOS 9.2. Turning off vibration still doesn't make Siri ding _on start_. Again, if I tap the microphone again to stop Siri it does beep twice. I literally just updated to iOS 9.2.

Comment: @Arc676 I have an iphone 6 plus running iOS 9.2, so I suppose there could be enough of a hardware difference between the two.  Beyond that I'm afraid to speculate.

Answer (score 0):

it was irritating but after I realized when you push button than say Siri it activates her and  the sounds are there during the session you use her.

Comment: We've already established that saying "hey Siri" will make it play a sound, but as I said with the other answer, this doesn't make it play the sound _on start_.

Answer (score 0):

My 6 was doing this. I had vibrate on ring set to off. I turned it back on, then Siri vibrated on activation. I turned it off again and Siri still continues to vibrate on activation, so this fixed my problem.

Answer (score -1):

Just go to Settings -> General -> Accessibility -> Home Button; scroll down to Siri and check off Voice Control:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  I don't see the setting you indicated.  What version of iOS are you referencing for that path?  What does turning off voice control do to solve this problem?  Are there any side-effects to doing this?  Please see [answer] for tips on answering questions here.